# Python flow control with Flag?

Tags: python, flags, flow-control

Matching a file in this form. It always begins with InvNo, ~EOR~ is End Of Record.

```
InvNo: 123
Tag1: rat cake
Media: d234
Tag2: rat pudding
~EOR~
InvNo: 5433
Tag1: strawberry tart
Tag5: 's got some rat in it 
~EOR~
InvNo: 345
Tag2: 5
Media: d234
Tag5: rather a lot really
~EOR~
```

It should become

```
IN 123
UR blabla
**
IN 345
UR blibli
**
```

Where UR is a URL. I want to keep the InvNo as first tag. ** is now the end of record marker. This works:

```
impfile = filename[:4]
media = open(filename + '_earmark.dat', 'w')

with open(impfile, 'r') as f: 
    HASMEDIA = False
    recordbuf = ''

    for line in f:
        if 'InvNo: ' in line:
            InvNo = line[line.find('InvNo: ')+7:len(line)]  
            recordbuf = 'IN {}'.format(InvNo)

        if 'Media: ' in line:
            HASMEDIA = True
            mediaref = line[7:len(line)-1]

            URL = getURL(mediaref) # there's more to it, but that's not important now  
            recordbuf += 'UR {}\n'.format(URL))

        if '~EOR~' in line:
            if HASMEDIA:
                recordbuf += '**\n'
                media.write(recordbuf)
                HASMEDIA = False

            recordbuf = ''

media.close()
```

Is there a better, more Pythonic way? Working with the recordbuffer and the HASMEDIA flag seems, well, old hat. Any examples or tips for good or better practice?

(Also, I'm open to suggestions for a more to-the-point title to this post)

Answer (score 3):

You could set `InvNo` and `URL` initially to `None`, and only print a record when `InvNo` and `URL` are both not Falsish:

```
impfile = filename[:4]
with open(filename + '_earmark.dat', 'w') as media, open(impfile, 'r') as f:
    InvNo = URL = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('InvNo: '):
            InvNo = line[line.find('InvNo: ')+7:len(line)]  

        if line.startswith('Media: '):
            mediaref = line[7:len(line)-1]
            URL = getURL(mediaref) 

        if line.startswith('~EOR~'):
            if InvNo and URL:
                recordbuf = 'IN {}\nUR {}\n**\n'.format(InvNo, URL)
                media.write(recordbuf)
            InvNo = URL = None
```

---

Note: I changed `'InvNo: ' in line` to `line.startswith('InvNo: ')` based on the *assumption* that `InvNo` always occurs at the beginning of the line. It appears to be true in your example, but the fact that you use `line.find('InvNo: ')` suggests that `'InvNo:'` might appear anywhere in the line.

If `InvNo:` appears only at the beginning of the line, then use `line.startswith(...)` and remove `line.find('InvNo: ')` (since it would equal 0).

Otherwise, you'll have to retain `'InvNo:' in line` and `line.find` (and of course, the same goes for `Media` and `~EOR~`).
The problem with using code like `'Media' in line` is that if the `Tags` can contain anything, it might contain the string `'Media'` without being a true field header.

Comment: Thanks! Re your notes: I'm using 'find' because the input files start with a byte order mark, so 'startswith' would miss the first InvNo. Good point on field contents matching `'Media: '`, as well.

Comment: To handle the BOM as well as avoid the pitfall regarding using `find`, open the file with [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open), and specify the encoding. If it is a UTF-8 encoded file, specify the encoding as `'utf-8_sig'`. Then the BOM will be correctly interpreted without becoming mixed in with the textual data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version if you don't want to slice and if you ever need to write to the same output file again, you may not, you can change 'w' to 'a'.

```
with open('input_file', 'r') as f, open('output.dat', 'a') as media:
    write_to_file = False
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('InvNo:'):
            first_line = 'IN ' + line.split()[1] + '\n'
        if line.startswith('Media:'):
            write_to_file = True
        if line.startswith('~EOR~') and write_to_file:
            url = 'blabla' #Put getUrl() here
            media.write(first_line + url + '\n' + '**\n')
            write_to_file = False
            first_line = ''
```